Facebook authentication Ineligible for Submission
I'm trying to implement authentication using Facebook in my nestjs app.
But I'm stuck creating the app on developers.facebook.com. Indeed, in all the tutorials I have watched, I have never seen the screen that I have.
[Currently Ineligible for Submission
Your submission is missing data in the following fields:
App icon (1024 x 1024)
Privacy Policy URL
User data deletion
Category][1]

Do I necessarily have to publish my application to be able to make simple requests?
thank you in advance
